# Can't see any fluid mesh in any view after i bake it in blender 3.0.0

Tags: fluid-simulation

I can't find any fluid mesh after I bake it in blender 3.0.0. I bake the fluid simulation and the mesh separately. I'm sure the mesh was baked because the processing bar showed up. and the mesh parameters are grey, Free Mesh bottom was enabled.  But still, I couldn't see the mesh in any view. I'm using blender 3.0.0 in M1 chip iMac.  Does anyone have a similar issue?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that fluid mesh baking is not creating a new object in the scene, but basically turning the domain object into the scene. As I previously set my domain cube viewport visibility into bounds rather than the default solid mode. the mesh that has been generated from the domain object was displayed as bounds as well.